Forward third party URL to another URL
Need to point one domain to another domain and retain the original URL.
Currently I'm working working with a third party client who owns a domain that needs traffic forwarded to a domain that I own but they would like the URL to remain as the original.
I'm hosting my domain and project on Cloudflare Pages, the third party is using Constellix for their DNS provider.
My question is this, is there a standard method for this use case? I'm just getting into needing something like this and the third party has little experience on this particular process as well.
I've used an https forward and ran into header and certificate issues. Also used frame redirect, this caused an issue with CSS media queries on mobile devices.

(This may or may not be a coding question, so I'm just going to go for it.)
There are two basic scenarios:

You need to re-direct the traffic, so you need a web proxy.

There are many "reverse-proxy" solutions. They are often configurable, but their focus is to appear as a web server (no proxy-client configuration), and they forward the request to the "origin" or "destination", the source of the actual content.
Most of them are customizable, to preserve or manage various headers. (Anything more than this is a question for server-fault.)
2- You need very specific HTTP (esp. header) or SSL management. You'd need a custom web-app, which has the same role as above, but is essentially a web-app that performs like a reverse proxy, but has the features of a content management solution.
For that, the programing questions could be asked in stack overflow, on how to do things (like maybe archive everyone's web activity to the corp gift store, on their birthday... for example, that would require code :) )
